# Avoid nested for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

How can I avoid the following for loop in R?

```
  for(a in 1:n){
    for(b in a:n){
      D[a,b] <- function(a,b)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try with `outer` i.e. `m1 <- outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(n), FUN = '+);  (NA^lower.tri(D)) * m1`

Comment: @Barbara I have a nested loop but it takes so much time when `n` gets bigger. So I need to avoid them. But I cannot do that because the inner loop uses `a` which is a variable from the outer loop.

Comment: If you have more code/context for us so we can understand what you're aiming for, we might be able to give more focused advice on whether your problem can be vectorized or not.

Comment: You should vectorize `function`  to avoid one of the looping.